# Is prophylaxis a feature of the hypermodern school?

Tags: history, books, terminology

Wikipedia mentions prophylaxis in the article of hypermodernism in chess. But is it really a feature of the hypermodern school? I have not seen prophylaxis in any other book or article about hypermodernism in chess. One exeption is the chapter about prophylaxis in the book My Shstem, which is also describing hypermodern chess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because Nimzowitch  was the foremost figure amongst the hypermoderns, you can't mention hypermodern school without Nimzowitch. And the prophylaxis idea first introduced by him, in his famous book Mein System. If we would call him the father of modern chess, it wouldn't be wrong.

His ideas was challenging the dogmatic rules set by Tarrasch, which widely considered as the *best* strategy at the time.

There is an excellent book named Secrets of Modern Chess Strategy: Advances since Nimzowitch, which covers prophylaxis and lot more. I recommend you to read it.